# Need to detect googletagmanager text using regex with script tags

Tags: regex

I need to detect googletagmanager from the following script using regex

Tried following code

```
(<script.*?src="(.*?! gtag)")(</script>)
```

Following are 2 scripts

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-826130319"></script>

<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-T39RFHR');</script>
```

Comment: so you want to detect this script ? <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-826130319"></script>

Comment: yes, I want to detect script with googletagmanager

Comment: is this fixed ? https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag or anything could come before gtag ?

Comment: It is either gtag or googletagmanager

Answer (score 0):

This is matching your script

```
(<script)([a-zA-Z="'\s])*(src="|')(https:\/\/www\.googletagmanager\.com\/gtag\/)([a-zA-Z=\-\?\d])*("|')([a-zA-Z="'\s])*(>)(<\/script>)
```

check this on [online regex checker](https://regex101.com/)

The difficult part was for things surrounding , i.e ahead and before of that string, so if any change in script you can easily do here not much of an issue

Comment: @arjun if you dont figure out change in small text there , you can comment here I will update it, thats just a 1 min fix